# Is it essential to include icons for all drawable folders in app bundle?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm going to use app bundle for an android app. But earlier I used normal apk for the deployment. In the project I only have icons for drawable xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. But for the dynamic delivery, is it essential to include icons in all drawable folders?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will warn you if you are missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not essential, it will work just as well as before.

However providing icons in lower density offers smaller APKs for devices that have smaller screen densities and those users will be grateful :)